# Building lambda expression for filtering in list of dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, filtering

So, Hello everyone!

I have next class:

```
public class ExportItem
    {
        public Dictionary<string, object> Container { get; set; }

        public ExportItem()
        {
            Container = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
    }
```

And `Container` in my case contains a set of pair "name of the property - value of this property".

Next, I have `List<ExportItem>`.

The problem is, I want to filter through this list, using (as I think, the best way) dynamically builded expressions.

I know, how to build simple expression for the case, when I'm having traditional class with properties:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(People), property);
var member = Expression.Property(parameter, "Id"); //x.Id
var constant = Expression.Constant(3);
var body = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant); //x.Id >= 3
var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<People, bool>>(body, parameter); //x => x.Id >= 3
```

But in my case I should filter not through property `Id`, but through collection of the Values of the dictionary.

I.e. I must take only those `ExportItem's`, in `Container` of which I have property with name (key), for example, "Age" and value, greater than "12". (I can easily convert values of the dictionary to strings and compare these strings - in this case it's not so critical).

I wonder if this even possible. If it is, please, guide me, how to create proper expression, otherwise, maybe you can offer better way to create filter in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write something like this:

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        //Initialize scenario
        var item1 = new ExportItem();
        var item2 = new ExportItem();
        var item3 = new ExportItem();
        item1.Container["ID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
        item1.Container["Name"] = "John Smith";
        item1.Container["DateOfBirth"] = new DateTime(2002, 10, 10);
        item2.Container["Name"] = "Alice";
        item2.Container["DateOfBirth"] = new DateTime(2004, 10, 20);
        item2.Container["ID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
        item3.Container["ID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
        item3.Container["Name"] = "Bob";
        item3.Container["DateOfBirth"] = "Invalid Date";
        List<ExportItem> myExportItems = new List<ExportItem>() { item1, item2, item3 };
        //Initialize filter (older than 12 years)
        Int32 myAge = 12;
        DateTime myAgeLimit = DateTime.Today.AddYears(myAge * -1);
        Predicate<KeyValuePair<String, Object>> myFilter = (x => (x.Key == "DateOfBirth") && (x.Value is DateTime) && ((DateTime)x.Value) < myAgeLimit);
        //Filter the according items
        var myResult = (from e in myExportItems from e2 in e.Container where myFilter(e2) select e);
        //Execute something 
        Console.Out.WriteLine($"Older than {myAge} years old:");
        foreach (var myExportItem in myResult) {
            var myContainer = myExportItem.Container;
            String myID = "unknown";
            String myName = "unknown";
            String myDateOfBirth = ((DateTime)myContainer["DateOfBirth"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            try {
                myID = ((Guid)myContainer["ID"]).ToString("D");
            } catch { }
            try {
                myName = ((String)myContainer["Name"]);
            } catch { }
            Console.WriteLine($"myID={myID}");
            Console.WriteLine($"myID={myName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"myID={myDateOfBirth}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }

}

public class ExportItem {

    public Dictionary<string, object> Container { get; set; }

    public ExportItem() {
        Container = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

}
```

PS: Storing an age is evil. Store the date of birth instead.

Comment: I know, that was only the simpliest example))) That works great, thank you very much!